# Accessing the bits in char through a bitfield

Tags: c++, c, char, bit

I want to access the bits in a `char` individually.  There are several questions and answers on this topic here on SO, but they all suggest to use boolean mathematics.  However, for my use it would be more convenient if I could simply name the bits separately.  So I was thinking of just accessing the `char` through a bitfield, like so

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    bool _1 : 1, _2 : 1, _3 : 1, _4 : 1, _5 : 1, _6 : 1, _7 : 1, _8 : 1;
} bits;

int main() {
    char c = 0;
    bits *b = (bits *)&c;
    b->_3 = 1;
    printf("%s\n", c & 0x4 ? "true" : "false");
}
```

This compiles without errors or warnings with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic test.c`.  When running the resulting executable with `valgrind` it reports no memory faults.  The assembly generated for the `b->_3 = 1;` assignment is `or eax, 4` which is sound.

**Questions**

- Is this defined behaviour in C?
- Is this defined behaviour in C++?

N.B.: I'm aware that it might cause trouble for mixed endianness but I only have little endian.

Comment: What is your use case that `b->_3` is more convenient than `b & 4`?

Comment: @melpomene For a small string I want to store flags in the last `char` where the first 4 bits are the remaining size, the 5th bit is a flag for heap allocation and the remaining 3 are unused.  Rather than having to think about all the extraction masks it would be easiest to just cast the last bit to `struct { size_t remaining : 4; bool allocated : 1; bool unused1 : 1, unused2 : 1, unused2 : 1; }` and then access `remaining` and `allocated` directly.  It also makes writing the bits easier.

Comment: Endianess and bit ordering are not the same. `size_t remaining : 4` is implementation specific. Portable bitfields are only `int` and `bool`

Comment: @KamilCuk "portable bitfields" are a contradiction.  They don't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this defined behaviour in C?
>   Is this defined behaviour in C++?

TL;DR: no it is not.

The boolean bitfield is well-defined as far as: `bool` is an ok type to use for bit-fields, so you are guaranteed to get a blob of 8 booleans allocated somewhere in memory. If you access boolean `_1`, you'll get the same value as last time you accessed that variable.

What is not defined is the bit order. The compiler may insert padding bits or padding bytes as it pleases. All of that is implementation-defined and non-portable. So you can't really know where `_1` is located in memory or if it is the MSB or LSB. None of that is well-defined.

However, `bits *b = (bits *)&c;` accessing a `char` through a struct pointer is a strict aliasing violation and may also cause alignment problems. It is undefined behavior in C and C++ both. You would need to at least show this struct into a `union` with a `char` to dodge strict aliasing, but you may still get alignment hiccups (and C++ frowns at type punning through unions).

(And going from boolean type to character type can give some real crazy results too, see [_Bool type and strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163870/bool-type-and-strict-aliasing))

---

None of this is convenient at all - bitfields are very poorly defined. It is *much* better to simply do:

```
c |= 1u << n;     // set bit n
c &= ~(1u << n);  // clear bit n
```

This is portable, type generic and endianess-independent.

(Though to dodge change of signedness due to implicit integer promotions, it is good practice to always cast the result of `~` back to the intended type: `c &= (uint8_t) ~(1u << n);`).

Note that the type `char` is entirely unsuitable for bitwise arithmetic since it may or may not be signed. Instead you should use `unsigned char` or preferably `uint8_t`.

Comment: C++ also has `std::bitset` which works much better than bit-fields, though I don't know enough of how well that one plays out across various compilers to recommend it. It seems to work ok on mainstream PC compilers, but beyond that I don't know.

Comment: “accessing a `char` through a struct pointer is a strict aliasing violation” That is exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: @HenriMenke But you have numerous other forms of poorly-specified behavior here too. Where the most severe is probably the possibility for misaligned access, depending on CPU.