# Accessing individual bits of unsigned integer through pointer to struct with bit fields in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, bit-fields

Let's say we have a struct defined like:

```
struct S_BF {
    unsigned first_bit : 1;
    unsigned second_bit : 1;
    unsigned rest : 30;
}
```

And a pointer to `S_BF` struct:

```
struct S_BF*  bf;
```

If we have a variable:

```
unsigned int p = 0;
```

How can we make `bf` point to `p` so we can modify the value of `p` by modifying its bit fields, for example, if we want to change the value of `p` to 2, we can do this:

```
bf->second_bit = 1;
```

Comment: The only conforming way is to use a union. Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531589

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the bits in char through a bitfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531589/accessing-the-bits-in-char-through-a-bitfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with wanting to access the bits of `unsigned p` with a pointer of type `struct S_BF*` is that it violates the *strict alias* rule [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6). The rule is designed to prevent accessing an object of one type by using a pointer to another. (there are various exceptions, but the intent of the rule is to prevent the type-punning of pointers)

The only standard conforming way to access the bits of an `unsigned` through a pointer to `struct S_BF` it to make the bits the same bits through a `union` between `struct S_BF` and `unsigned`. You must can access the bits of `struct S_BF` through a pointer to `struct S_BF`, and make the `struct S_BF` and `unsigned` the same through the union without violating the string aliasing rule. A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S_BF {               /* bitfield struct */
    unsigned first_bit : 1;
    unsigned second_bit : 1;
    unsigned rest : 30;
};

union s2u {                 /* union bitfield struct/unsigned */
    struct S_BF s;
    unsigned u;
};

int main (void) {

    union s2u s2u = { .u = 0 };             /* union initialized zero */
    struct S_BF *bf = &s2u.s;               /* pointer to bitfield */
    unsigned sz = 32;                       /* no. of bits in unsigned */

    bf->second_bit = 1;         /* set second bit 1 */
    bf->rest = 0x2aaaaaaa;      /* alternating bits 1010101... */

    while (sz--)    /* loop sz times, using unsigned value in union */
        putchar (s2u.u >> sz & 1 ? '1' : '0');  /* output bits */

    putchar ('\n');
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

The above example would result in the following output:

```
$ ./bin/bitfield_union
10101010101010101010101010101010
```