# Does nullptr_t break type punning or pointer conversions?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, nullptr, type-punning, c23

Consider this union:

```
typedef union
{
  void*      vptr;
  nullptr_t  nptr;
} pun_intended;
```

`nullptr_t` is supposedly compatible with `void*` <sup>1)</sup>. Ok so what if we initialize the `void*` to some non-zero value?

```
pun_intended foo = { .vptr = (void*)42 };
```

- This conversion is supposedly legit (impl.defined) as per C23 6.3.2.3 §4, or at least it was until `nullptr_t` was introduced.
- And what about union type punning? Also supposedly legit.
- And what about inspecting any type's internal representation in C using a character type pointer, well-defined until C23, 6.3.2.3 §7.

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef union
{
  void*      vptr;
  nullptr_t  nptr;    
} pun_intended;

int main(void)
{
  pun_intended foo = { .vptr = (void*)42 };
  printf("Value: %" PRIuPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)foo.vptr);

  if(foo.nptr != (void*)42)
  {
    puts("It does not have value 42.");
    if(foo.nptr == nullptr)  
      puts("Because it's a nullptr.");
    else
      puts("But it's not a nullptr.");

    unsigned int val = *(unsigned char*)&foo; // little endian assumption here
    printf("And it has value %d.\n", val);

    if(foo.vptr != nullptr)
    {
      puts("foo.vptr is however not a nullptr.");
    }
  }
}
```

Output on clang 16 -std=c2x:

```
Value: 42
It does not have value 42
Because it's a nullptr
And it has value 42.
foo.vptr is however not a nullptr
```

Output on gcc 13.2 -std=c2x:

```
Value: 42
It does not have value 42.
But it's not a nullptr.
And it has value 42.
foo.vptr is however not a nullptr.
```

My question: Is anything of the above (which was previously well-defined or impl.defined) now undefined/unspecied behavior? If so, where is that stated? Or are these scenarios simply not considered in C23 - a defect?

---

<sup>1)</sup> Source: C23 n3096 draft 7.21.2

> The size and alignment of `nullptr_t` is the same as for a pointer to character type. An object representation of the value `nullptr` is the same as the object representation of a null pointer value of type `void*`.

Comment: `nullptr_t` [is different from all pointer or arithmetic types ... and has exactly one value `nullptr`.](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf#subsection.7.21.2) Can this be squared with a `nullptr_t` holding the value 42?

Comment: @adabsurdum I think the bottom line is that no value "nullptr" exists in the real world where computers live. They have to name the exact representation of it, such as "a pointer of size `sizeof(void*)` with all bytes set to zero". Otherwise I don't think this type is any improvement over NULL, quite the contrary as it seems to make C less suitable for hardware-related programming.

Comment: Similarly if a `nullptr_t` must have representation `nullptr`, then what exactly is "not `nullptr`"? A trap representation?

Comment: From C23 7.21.2p2 regarding `nullptr_t`:  *"It has only a very limited use
in contexts where this type is needed to distinguish `nullptr` from other expression types"*, so it's probably not intended to be used in this way.

Comment: Re “`nullptr_t` is supposedly compatible with `void*`”: Who supposes that and why? “Compatible” has a specific meaning in C. Largely, it means that two types can be completed to be the same type. The fact that one type can be converted to another implicitly does not mean they are compatible. The fact that two types have the same size and representation does not mean they are compatible. `nullptr_t` is not compatible with `void *`.

Comment: The problem seems similar to that of performing an lvalue conversion on a `_Bool` object that has somehow (for example by `union` type-punning) been set to a value other than 0 or 1, which as far as I can tell would result in UB. That's probably already been asked about in another question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil C23 7.21.2 says so. Source added to the question.

Comment: @IanAbbott I recall this fun little display of UB: [_Bool type and strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163870/bool-type-and-strict-aliasing). It is quite similar to this indeed, both problems happen when you apply low-level programming to artificial types without well-defined representations. The kind of academic people who come up with these kind of artificial representations never had to implement CRC, walk patterns, wear leveling etc to guarantee memory coherency.

Comment: Having the same object representation does not make two types compatible. `void *` and `char *` have the same object representation but are not compatible. `short` and `int` may have the same object representation but are not compatible in C implementations in which they do.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Having the same representation ought to mean that you can `memcpy` them into each other seamlessly, except some compilers seem to have added diagnostics if you try to pass a `nullptr_t` to certain functions. If C chose to make artificial restrictions regarding assignment on top of that, that's another story.

Comment: @Lundin, yes, you can `memcpy` them. That is not what “compatible” means. “Compatible” has a technical definition in the C standard. It is about type semantics, not representation. Largely, two types are compatible if they are the same except for any missing parts. E.g. `int []` and `int [17]` are compatible because they are both arrays of `int` and differ only in that one is missing the size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Ok so what if we initialize the `void*` to some non-zero value?

C 2023 N3096 7.21.2 3 explicitly answers this. After telling us that the representation of a `nullptr` value in the `nullptr_t` type is the same as for a null pointer value in the `void *` type, it tells us what happens if there is a different sequence of byte values in a `nullptr_t` object:

> … if the object representation is different, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: ugh.  Just what C needs: syntactic sugar that adds the wholly-new concept of an immutable type to C and opens the door to weird corner-case UB and bugs.  Straight from the too-complex-to-understand, must-be-everything-to-everybody font of craziness that is C++.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It's nothing special. The UB mentioned in this answer is the exact same UB you get if you perform an lvalue conversion of a non-value representation of *any* type, not just `nullptr_t`, and non-value representations (previously called trap representations) have been around for ages. You're still free to write invalid representations to an object of type `nullptr_t`, or to have an invalid representation in such an object before you initialize it.

Comment: `nullptr_t` isn't really immutable, or introducing any new concepts. It's just a type that happens to only have one value. `const` types are closer to immutable, and those have been around for ages.

Comment: Just found this part now. Can union type punning always be said to be an lvalue conversion though?

Answer (score 2):

IMO it is UB:

6.3.2.3

> If a null pointer constant or a value of the type nullptr_t (***which
> is necessarily the value `nullptr`*** )...

6.5.4.4

> A pointer type shall not be converted to any floating type. A floating
> type shall not be converted to any pointer type. The type nullptr_t
> shall not be converted to any type other than void , bool or a pointer
> type. ***No type other than `nullptr_t` shall be converted to `nullptr_t`***

Here you convert `void *` to `nullptr_t` via union which is explicitly prohibited.

You can convert `nullptr_t` to `void *` via this union but not `void *` to `nullptr_t`

IMO `nullptr_t` exists only to introduce `nullptr` constant and I do not see any practical use of this type.

Comment: Although... if I can convert from nullptr_t to void*, and void* is explicitly a type through which any other object pointer conversion is possible, I should also be able to convert from void* to nullptr_t. Or otherwise nullptr_t also breaks void pointers as a generic type, in addition to all other oddities shown in the question.

Comment: @Lundin  `No type other than nullptr_t shall be converted to nullptr_t` sounds quite definitive. And you are right - I agree, but it does not change the working used. BTW `nullptr_t` exists only to introduce `nullptr` an I do not see any practical use of this type

Comment: @Lundin: Re “Or otherwise nullptr_t also breaks void pointers as a generic type”: It does not break pointers because `nullptr_t` is not a pointer type. Pointer types are derived types; they are derived from object or function types per C 2023 N3096 6.2.525. `nullptr_t` is a new type. Even if it were a pointer type, it would not break the rules about conversions between pointers to object types because it would not be a pointer to an object type.